# Building dacpac referencing master.dacpac inside a windows container

Tags: msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to build a .sqlproj referencing master database inside a windows container, but i get this error:

> C:\src\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild.10.0.61804.210\lib\net46\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(559,5): Build error SQL72027: File
>   "C:\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac"
>   does not exist.

I read many threads about the problem, and from my understanding master.dacpac is only installed during Visual Studio installation phase. However inside the container I do not want to install VS.

If I copy the master.dacpac from my VS host installation path into the container, the project builds successfully.

My question is:

is there a cleaner way to build a .sqlproj from msbuild when it is referencing master.dacpac?
My current solution requires a pre-build script copying master.dacpac from visual studio installation folder to Dockerfile folder, and seems to me the wrong way to go.

At the moment my Dockerfile is like this (pseudo code)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS builder
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

WORKDIR C:\src

RUN nuget.exe install Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild

# copy master.dacpac into the container + manually deploy it for msbuild
RUN mkdir C:\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas
COPY master.dacpac C:\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac

# copy sqlproj source code into the container
COPY ${SQLPROJ_SRC_ROOT_DIR} .
RUN msbuild ${SQLPROJ_NAME_WITHOUTEXT}.sqlproj `
      /p:SQLDBExtensionsRefPath="C:\src\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild.10.0.61804.210\lib\net46" `
      /p:SqlServerRedistPath="C:\src\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild.10.0.61804.210\lib\net46"
```

Comment: You could add an external reference and change the path to the master.dacpac but not sure what building inside the container gets you over building elsewhere. You might look at the dacfx nuget package or something like poshssdtbuilddeploy to keep things in the container.

Comment: Thank you, I also installed inside the container dacfx as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15), but it is not installing master.dacpac

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you building inside the container?  Is it to have a container that does builds so you don't need to set up a new build machine?  If so, this is probably the cleanest way to do this short of setting up some mount points pointing to a local dacpac folder.  That could be another option for you.

Comment: This is exactly my point in using a build container, avoiding setting up the host machine. Using a mount point should work, but would tie the image to the host. Anyway this seems a working solution, thank you!